# Conditional Import of JavaScript module by Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a JavaScript Framework based on Webpack. There I want to import (or not) an arbitrary module (JavaScript file with a custom function exported as default) by a custom condition made in the Webpack configuration:

```
// in webpack.customSettings.js
module.exports = {
  const customJsFilePath = 'path/to/custom/js/file';
  // alternatively, if no import is desired:
  // const customJsFilePath = null;
};

// in webpack.config.js
const settings = require('./webpack.customSettings.js');
// ...
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': {
    PATH: JSON.stringify(settings.customJsFilePath || ''),
  },
});
```

This determines if and which custom module is required during the Webpack build process. So a dynamic import like the following seems to be unnecessary and not really efficient, because the path is already fixed at runtime and I don't want to load dynamically an extra file (chunk) during runtime in this case:

```
// somewhere in my main index.js
if (process.env.PATH) {
  import(`${process.env.PATH}/index.js`).then((module) => {
    const myFunc = module.default;
    // ...
  });
}
```

I would rather have the custom file included **directly** in my bundle by Webpack. Something like that:

```
// somewhere in my main index.js
const myFunc = awesomeGlobal.customFunc;
if (myFunc) {
  // ...
}
```

I know that the following doesn't work, unfortunately:

```
// in my main index.js
import customFunc from `${process.env.PATH}/index.js`;
```

But what can I do? Perhaps something in Webpack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I came up with the solution myself. I use the Webpack ProvidePlugin to provide the module conditionally:

```
// in webpack.customSettings.js
module.exports = {
  const customJsFilePath = 'path/to/custom/js/file';
  // alternatively, if no import is desired:
  // const customJsFilePath = null;
};

// in webpack.config.js
const settings = require('./webpack.customSettings.js');
// ...
new webpack.ProvidePlugin((() => {
  const addModules = {};

  if (settings.customJsFilePath) {
    addModules['window.myFunc'] = [settings.customJsFilePath, 'default'];
  }

  return addModules;
})()),

// in my main index.js
if (window.myFunc) {
  window.myFunc();
}
```